# Find start and end date of a given date string using moment?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

My date string is `August 2015`

I want to find start and end date of month `August 2015` using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com)

I tried as follows but not working,

```
moment(date).endOf('month').toDate()
```

How can I find the same?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: "Not working" is not a useful problem statement. Also, the code you've shown won't do *anything* -- you'd have to *use* the resulting object. And **please** search before posting. Looking at the duplicate that Pankaj linked, the most trivial search should have found that.